# Select overloaded function at runtime after type cannot be automatically inferred

Tags: generics, kotlin, overloading

I have a function that calls an overloaded function `funcA`. Lets say that we have different Types `A`, `B` and `C` which all implement the abstract class `Top<T extends Serializable>`. Now this given function `funcA` exists for the generic type `funcA(p0:Top<T extends Serializable>)` and also for the other given Types `funcA(p0:A)`, `funcA(p0:B)` etc.

Now I want to call that function when I only got a generic variable `it:Top<out Serializable>`. If I now just write `funcA(it)`, Kotlin cannot infer automatically which overloaded function to call, as the exact type is now erased.

What does work is to check for the given types and cast them before calling `funcA`:

```
when(it) {
    is A -> funcA(it)
    is B -> funcA(it)
    is C -> funcA(it)
    else -> error("Cannot infer correctly")
}
```

Is there any way to have this problem solved in a nicer way?

Comment: Can you make `funcA` an abstract method of your `Top` class?  That's usually the best approach, as the usual dynamic method dispatch will handle it all at runtime. (As this demonstrates, type erasure makes it really awkward to do that statically when generics are involved.)

Comment: In this case, the `funcA` method is from a Java-Library (https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) so I can't change that much.